# Python path in .bash_profile not respected

Tags: python, macos, path

Been Googling and searching here to no avail, so forgive me if this is a duplicate.

Basically, I installed Python 3.4 on my machine (Mac running Yosemite 10.10.2), but when I run `python` in Terminal, it starts up Python2.7.whatever, which I'm assuming is the version that is often mentioned as coming pre-installed on Macs. I've checked my ~/.bash_profile using vim, and here's what it currently contains:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Virtualenv Wrapper stuff
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Which, according to all the reading I've been doing, should work. But it isn't. Any and all thoughts as to why are appreciated.

Comment: Did you source your bash_profile after editing it?

Comment: Yup. This problem has persisted through multiple machine restarts over the past week or so, so I don't think that would be the issue anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would just type `python3` or `python3.4` to get a specific version. You should try that.

Most developers also use virtual environments which give you the ability to handle python versions and modules per application. There is an introduction at http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/