# Cookiecutter Django doesn't play nice with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've been trying to get a project started using Cookiecutter Django, and am unable to get the database hookup going properly.

Here's what I've done:

`pip install cookiecutter`

`cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django.git`

And then filled out the answers to all the questions and ran `pip install -r requirements/local.txt` as detailed [here](http://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/developing-locally.html).

Then, I ran psql and did:

```
CREATE DATABASE example;
CREATE USER example_user WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

Followed by `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://example_user:password@localhost:5432/example` (outside of psql but in my virtualenv, though I tried it outside the virtualenv as well).

Then, upon running `python manage.py migrate` as detailed in the above link, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _lo_lseek64
  Referenced from: /Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib in /Users/maxwellskala/.virtualenvs/shred/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

For full disclosure, I first tried to follow the guide found [here](http://blog.swapps.co/how-to-create-a-django-application-using-cookiecutter-and-django-1-8/#.Vgnl-hNViko) as well as the official docs, without success.

After a bunch of unsuccessful Googling I broke down and emailed another SO user who recommended I skip all the stuff about permissions and such and "just use the createdb part of that" which is what I explained above. I'm still getting the same error.

One theory I have is that it has something to do with the multiple versions of Python on my machine. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834016/python-path-in-bash-profile-not-respected?noredirect=1#comment53503803_32834016) question. Basically, if (in my proper virtualenv) I run `python manage.py migrate` I get the above error, but if I run `python 3.4 manage.py migrate`, I get

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'`

which also baffles me because I clearly have Django installed as per the pip call I made above.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your _psycopg.so library. See [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.db.psycopg.devel/5662) they say it might be built for the incorrect architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is with psycopg2 not loading. To fix:

1. Make sure your virtualenv is active.
2. Uninstall psycopg2 from your virtualenv (`pip uninstall psycopg2`). Check your virtualenv's site-packages dir to make sure it's gone.
3. Reinstall psycopg2 into your virtualenv. Since it looks like you're on OS X, you should be able to do this via `pip install psycopg2` or by reinstalling the local requirements.

Then to create your database, do `createdb shred` or whatever the name of your db is, as specified in your settings. This should match the value you entered for `repo_name`.

Comment: 4 years later I found your advice still usefull !